# iOS SKMaps architecture error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, skmaps

I am currently getting an error when I want to build project on a 64bit System. (iPad, iPhone).

I am getting this error :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /(project Path)/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /(project Path)/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAnnotation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapsInitSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapsService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On non 64-Bit Systems it works like a charm! But it shows error the other way around.

Need some guidance on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the SDK build for arm64. Send an email to dev@skobbler.com and you should receive the build.

Comment: Thanks get it from them :)

Comment: Update: now the default demo you receive in the download are (http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) contains also the arm64 library)